# How to apply 2D mask on a specific side of 3D array?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, mask

Suppose we have regular 3D array of shape `(n,n,n)` padded with `True`s. I would like to create an array of diagonal principal minors. They should be masks arrays. My approach can be described in a following way:

[image]

And my method looks like this:

```
def dpm(n):
    b = np.ones(shape=(n,n,n), dtype=bool)
    b[np.eye(n, dtype=bool)] = False
    b = b.swapaxes(1,2) # rotate in order to apply masking
    b[np.eye(n, dtype=bool)] = False
    b = b.swapaxes(1,2) # rotate back
    return b
```

I've noticed later from visualization that back rotation is not necessary. Example of output:

```
>>> dpm(3)
array([[[False, False, False],
        [False,  True,  True],
        [False,  True,  True]],

       [[ True, False,  True],
        [False, False, False],
        [ True, False,  True]],

       [[ True,  True, False],
        [ True,  True, False],
        [False, False, False]]])
```

Is there a way to mask an array without swapping axis with `b.swapaxes(1,2)`?

Comment: what is the objective: do you want to make it more efficient or do you want another method that just does not use swapaxes?

Comment: @Ehsan I'm looking for more ingrained ways of indexing than `np.swapaxes` which looks artificial. It's also OK if there's an easy way to fasten it.

Comment: considering swapaxes returns a view, I think this code is pretty fast and also compact enough. I am not sure how much more you can compact it. You can also just do `b.swapaxes(1,2)[np.eye(n, dtype=bool)] = False` instead of last three lines.

Comment: @Ehsan Alright, I trust that my method is efficient now because you mentioned that swapaxes returns a view. Actually, numpy supports advanced indexing like `b[mask1, mask2, mask3]` where masks are one-dimensional so I expected some way to specify 2D mask for specific axes. If there's no simple solution, I'll be convinced it's not supported

Comment: Of course you can combine masks first, then assign them, but I am not aware of a faster way to do it. One example is: `a2 = np.repeat(np.eye(n, dtype=bool)[:,None,:],n,1);b[a2]=False` but this certainly is slower than your original method.